# Ubuntu Installation Error

Tags: system-installation, syslinux

There is problem installing Ubuntu on my computer.

```
 Error : Failed to load ldlinux.c32
```

This error occurs when it starts to boot.

Comment: Make fresh installation medium. If you are in windows try Universal USB Installer .

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your bootable device with others programs (Etcher for example)